# C# assignment in test I can't wrap my head around

Tags: c#

I am doing a test, and there is a question so seemingly simple, but I do not know how I should do it. The first number row kinda makes sense how I should do it, but the second row , I have no idea. Can anyone help brighten my mind?

> Write the C # code that (using a loop: for, while, do-while, of your choice) can print the following two number rows:

```
-1280, -640, -320, -160, -80, -40, -20, -10 (parts with 2)
1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81 (a mixture of two number rows)
```

for the first one I just did:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    for (int i = -1280; i <= -10; i /= 2) 
    { 
       Console.WriteLine(i); 
    } 
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: can you include what code that you had tried?

Comment: @Lawraoke for the first one I just did:

    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                for (int i = -1280; i <= -10; i /= 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);


                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
    }

Comment: In case you can't understand the second row (I needed a few minutes two): it consists of two separate "number rows", 1-2-3-4-5-... where the numbers are increasing and 1-4-9-16-25-... where the square numbers are listed. The second row is the mixture of these two number rows, one from the first, one from the second, etc... I doubt anyone will help you with the code, but I hope this helps understanding the task.

Comment: @jps Please then, instead of the snark remark, will you enlighten me with the wisdom from 6th grade? Would be much appreciated

Comment: @helt12 I already add my answer, try take a look at below. **Update** your tried code to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first row

A number get to divide by 2

```
for( int x=-1280 ; x!= -10; x/2)
{ Console.WriteLine(x); }
```

your second row

A number is multiply by himself

```
for (int x = 1; x<9; x++)
{
 y = x*x;
 Console.WriteLine(x, y)
}
```

try to get an idea what is the coding that you are trying to perform and implement yourself, my code is just for you as references.

Comment: @helt12 you are welcome, by the way you should post the full question include what hardship you faced, what code you had tried etc, these fellas will help you by correcting your coding snytax instead of asking them for recoding :D 
Anyway if you find this answer helpful to you, try make it as an **accepted answer**

Comment: please use Console.Write, printf is not there in C#

Comment: @viveknuna yes, my bad let me update the answer

Answer (score -2):

Here you are:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("-1280, -640, -320, -160, -80, -40, -20, -10 (parts with 2)");
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine("1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81 (a mixture of two number rows)");
  }
}
```

Comment: that is somewhat an answer...

Comment: I like this guy